# D3 HSL color interpolation counterclockwise

Tags: d3.js, colors, hsl

In D3, HSL color interpolation always goes in the clockwise direction. If I go from yellow at 60 degrees to blue at 240 degrees it always goes through green at 120 degrees. Reversing the interpolation colors changes the endpoints of yellow and blue, but not the green between them. How can the HSL interpolation go counterclockwise, so that magenta at 300 degrees is between blue and yellow?

Comment: Have you tried simply inverting the sign of the degree value?